# problems can be there/problems can there be/problems there can be

Tags: word-order

**There can be a lot of problems.**

How can I rephrase the sentence?

> 1 I don’t understand what kind of problems can be there.
>
> 2 I don’t understand what kind of problems can there be.
>
> 3 I don’t understand what kind of problems there can be.

Comment: That isn't rephrasing, it's adding something to the sentence! Only (3) is valid.

Comment: I think they're *all* valid. The first one carries a slightly different meaning, because ***there*** literally refers to some contextually-established location, whereas in the other two it's just an idiomatic non-specific reference *(**There's** no-one here, **There** was a thunderclap)*. The second one is just a less common sequence than the third, but I wouldn't say it's syntactically invalid. But personally, I'd prefer something like *I don’t understand what kind of problems **could arise***.

Comment: Please [describe what your research indicated](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) about word order as it applies here. Otherwise, anyone who answers might be doing unnecessary work, tell you things that you already know, etc.